# How to call the function in another class in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Hi everyone This is my App.js class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage, setQuickButtons, toggleMsgLoader } from '../index';

class Calender extends React.Component {
 state = {
 startDate: new Date()
};
handleChange = date => {
this.setState({
  startDate: date,
 });
};
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
 <form className="rcw-sender" onSubmit= {this.props.handleNewUserMessage}>
  <DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <button type="submit" className="rcw-send">
      <img src={submit} className="rcw-send-icon" alt="send" />
    </button>
  </form>
   </div>
   );
  }
 }


export default class App extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
  addResponseMessage('Welcome to this awesome chat!');
}
handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {    
toggleMsgLoader();
setTimeout(() => {
  toggleMsgLoader();      
  if (newMessage === 'Enter your date') {
  renderCustomComponent(Calender)

  } else {
    addResponseMessage(newMessage);
  }
 }, 2000);
}
 handleQuickButtonClicked = (e) => {
  addResponseMessage('Selected ' + e);
  setQuickButtons([]);
 }
 render() {
   return (
    <Widget
      title="Bienvenido"
      subtitle="Asistente virtual"
      senderPlaceHolder="Escribe aquí ..."
      handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
      handleQuickButtonClicked={this.handleQuickButtonClicked}
      badge={1}
    />
   );
   } 
  }
```

Now my intention is i want to send Calendar component output that means date of birth to App class handleNewUserMessage function.User will entered DOB by using Calendar component and then submitted it will directly go to the App class handleNewUserMessage function.How to send the DOB value to App class function

Thank you

Comment: add `Calender` component to `App` like you used `Widget` and pass a callback to `Calender` component. if you can't use `Calender` component in `App`, you can use `redux` and then use `componentWIllreceiveProps` lifecycle method or something like that

Comment: What is `renderCustomComponent` do ?

Answer (score 3):

When you render you component

```
<Calender />
```

pass a function handleDateSet as prop

```
<Calender handleDateSet={this.handleDateSet}>
```

then in your handleChange

```
handleChange = date => {
  this.props.handleDateSet(date); // this will send date to parent prop
  this.setState({
  startDate: date,
  });
```

};

I suggest you read [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in React docs before you move forward.

Good Luck!